# call inherited method that I've overriden

Tags: php

lets say I have this:

```
class Banana {
    public function GimmeFive() {
        echo "five";
    }
}

class FancyBanana extends Banana {
    public function GimmeFive() {
        echo "high";
        //somehow call the inherited GimmeFive()
    }
}
```

essentially I want to add on some stuff to the function defined in the parent class, can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parent` -

```
parent::GimmeFive()
```